# is a function a union or a record type?

Tags: f#

Scott has a [nice talk](https://youtu.be/Up7LcbGZFuo?t=1064) about domain modeling in F#, and presents the following slide:

[image]

**Is the `Deal` type a record or union type?**

My question is regarding this line:

`type Deal = Deck -> (Deck*Card)`

I'm not sure I understand this. How can we simply create a function and shove it into a type? I thought that the data and functionality are supposed to be separate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. It's a function type, more precisely it's an alias for the function type described by the signature `Deck -> (Deck * Card)`. The way aliases work is that you can use them to make things clearer wherever you state a type yourself, but if the compiler infers the type, that will always be the original unaliased type.

So in this case, wherever the type `Deal` is given, any function that takes a `Deck` and returns a tuple of `Deck` and `Card` will be accepted.

Comment: how would you use this?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' If we take the type alias out of it, do you understand how you'd work with a parameter or variable of type `Deck -> (Deck * Card)`? If so, you'd use `Deal` by writing `f: Deal` instead of `f: Deck -> (Deck * Card)` and everything else stays exactly the same.